# Solr merge reaching io limits on amazon ec2

Tags: linux, io, solr, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

We use apache-solr with over 10 million documents with a merge factor 2. It is hosted on amazon ec2 (amazon linux) with ebs volumes attached.Index resides on ebs.During merge, the io limit is reached and causing issues.
Is there any way to limit iops at process level or at particular disk level? 
or can we slow down solr merging?
Thanks

Comment: How does EC2/EBS react when you hit the "io limit"?

Comment: Most of the times it should be fine, but sometimes the volume will stop responding. Had to force detach and re-attach it once.

Comment: What do you think about just filing a support request with Amazon to ask them what to do?

Comment: of-course i did, i was advised to go little easy with io. But solr doesn't allow me to control it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mount several EBS in a RAID volume to get a higher throughput. [This post](http://orion.heroku.com/past/2009/7/29/io_performance_on_ebs/) from Heroku provides interesting facts of EBS io performance.

It's not a direct answer to your question but it will push the limit (if you are not already using RAID).

Comment: seems like thats the only way now.

Comment: Have a look also to [EC2 Ephemeral Disks vs EBS Volumes in RAID](http://victortrac.com/EC2_Ephemeral_Disks_vs_EBS_Volumes) to get additional performance facts

Comment: Ok, i expected some option in solr to control the speed as it can be a problem anytime.

Answer (score 0):

solr merging can be made less frequent by increasing the merge factor.